# How to handle multiple events at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a little game in JS where a lot of events occurs and often at the same time (like modify html elements or globals js variables..)

To handle this, i'm using a "setInterval" wich loop every 1ms to look in a table if there is something to do ("requests")

I populate the table every time i need to change something on the page, but sometimes i need change several differents things at the same time.

The problem is that it does not update at the same time, it's delayed when there is like 2,3 or more requests at the same time. I would like this to be instant and if there is 2 requests or more to do at the exact same time, it should do it at the same time and not delaying each requests (example of requests : updating the width of a div in jquery).

Thanks for the help..

```
var queue = {};

var fixedUpdate = setInterval(function() { //do all the requests in queue 

    $.each(queue, function(key, val) { //for each request present in the queue

        //do something (requests are about updating display or some global variables)

        /*...*/

        //after completing the request we delete it from the queue
        delete queue[key];
    });

}, 1);
```

Comment: You cannot expect `setInterval` to give you a fixed interval - it can vary a great deal, and 1ms is generally too fine a resolution.

Comment: this is a bad news :( does there are any alternative ?

Comment: you're going about the whole thing the wrong way - JS is not a realtime environment, it is an asynchronous environment.  Without knowing more about what you're doing it's tough to give you pointers, but for updating anything on screen, you should hook to `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: basically i 'm creating a game where you can see HEALTH BARS moving up and down (like if you got damage or healings on it), so i need a lot of update in a very small amount of time

Comment: @user4792376 - are you trying to do an animation?  If so, there are much, much better ways to do an animation and LOTS of code on the web already (including stuff built into jQuery).

Comment: animation for the display side but also handling data on the script size since you can interact with the BARS

Comment: nothing happens "at the same time" in JS.

Comment: @user4792376 - Your code NEEDS to be rewritten to be event driven, not timer polling driven.  Since you haven't included code for the overall scheme here and have not really explained the architecture, we can't make more concrete recommendations than that.  But, I would suggest you go do some reading about "event driven Javascript".

Comment: Once you understand what we've been trying to hint at here (asynchronous/event driven JS), you'll come to an 'Aha' moment that will be very satisfying. That's possibly the most fundamental thing to get about JS.

Comment: this is what i did for now : http://imgur.com/8i4bkFG

Comment: (every change on the display should trigger at the same time : every 1000ms) but well as i coded it and what you said i guess it's not possible)

Comment: can't you separate updating the screen from updating the data?  Update all the data and then update the screen when you have all valid updated data.

Comment: this is what i do, i'm updating all variables in the queue loop and after finishing the loop, i'm updating the display with jquery

Here is the full version of the setinterval : https://jsfiddle.net/qyvgtmqp/

Comment: @user4792376 - the relevant part of your architecture is in how things get added to the queue (which is not what you are showing in your jsFiddle).  That's where you need to make changes.  When something is added to the queue (which will presumably occur on some event), then you need to call a `processQueue()` function which triggers the code you now have in your interval timer.  Then, you will get immediate response, not a slower timer response and your code will be appropriately event driven.

Comment: Can you explain again what exactly is the problem in your jsFiddle?  I see two bars advancing from left to right until they each say "dead".  What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: the two bars should change at the exact same time (since each event is set to start at 0 and repeat every 1000ms). Here you can see it's delayed

Comment: OK, you cannot assume accuracy of Javascript timers.  It's a single threaded system and timers fire in "approximately" the time you requested.   The usual way to do an accurate animation is to use a timer as an update trigger only and to calculate the elapsed time from the beginning of the animation each time the timer calls an update function and use the actual elapsed time as your indicator for where to draw the animation.  These animation draws will always show accurately with respect to time regardless of how accurately the update timers are.  Continued in next comment...

Comment: Or said another way, whenever it draws, it draws accurately by calculating actual elapsed time.  So, in your case, if death is supposed to happen in a certain amount of time, then you update the bar on a known timer (say every 100ms) and you recalculate based on the current system time minus the start time how far the bar should be an you draw it exactly accurate as of that moment.  I don't understand the logic of your app enough to know exactly how to fit that into what you're doing.  But, the crux of the issue is that you cannot assume that each bar gets exactly synchronized timers.

Comment: Death should not happen in a certain time, it happens when the bar reach 0, and the bar loose health when it get damage, and of course damage is random, not always the same number, multiple different damage can happen on the same bar at the same time ect.. I think JS is not the appropriated language to use :(

Comment: If damage has randomness, then why do both bars proceed the same.  If they are supposed to be the same, then use the same event to draw them both, not separate events on separate timers.  Your app absolutely can be programmed in Javascript, just not with the architecture you are using.  FYI, here are two separate, but identical animations each running on their own timers: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n2608tad/

Comment: because i simplified it in my example but in fact i need to be able to do damage separately on each bars, since there will be some actions too from clicking on bars (it will increase the bar as a HEAL) ect.. I may have find something after seeing your fiddle i will try it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh my god just found what was causing the delay.... I had a function who was creating a random repeat time between two values (min max), but i failed the math in it and the function was returning a random value EVEN when you give it the two same min and max values... this is so dumb.... Thanks you for your time, how can i give you rep ?

Comment: Since you can't upvote yet, there's not much to do to give me rep.  I'd suggest you just either post your own answer and accept it or delete the question so one way or the other, it isn't left hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found what was causing the delay.... I had a function who was creating a random repeat time between two values (min max), but i failed the math in it and the function was returning a random value EVEN when you give it the two same min and max values..

Answer (score 2):

Polling a queue is not an appropriate way to write Javascript.  Because of the single threaded nature of Javascript in the browser, you will not get good responsiveness in pretty much any of your app if you are continuously polling a queue on a short interval.

Javascript is built from the ground up to be an event driven language and it works effectively when it is used in an event driven fashion.

You must have events that are putting things in the queue.  You should trigger processing of the queue WHEN something is added to the queue, NOT have some separate timer that polls the queue.  Trigger the processing of the queue WHEN things are added to the queue will also give you immediate response rather than having a timer delay.

And, further whenever you finish processing an event in the queue, your code should check to see if there is something else in the queue and process that too.  This way, you get all queued items processed as close to when they were added to the queue as possible in a single threaded environment.

Further, the main browser Javascript is single threaded so you will only ever be processing one queued item at a time.  You cannot process multiple requests at the exact same instant.  The browser does have real threads with webWorkers, but those cannot access the DOM so are probably not relevant here.

Further still, per the HTML5 specification, the minimum time for `setInterval()` is 5ms and that is only if there is not other code running at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but as i was afraid, this is not compatible with what i want to do.. i'm looking for an alternative way to do it, i can go with Unity but JS was more easy for me :/

Comment: @user4792376 - I think what's really going on is that your current thought on how your app is designed is not compatible with how Javascript works.  I am quite sure there IS a design for your game that is compatible with the way Javascript works, but it would require some new design thinking.